# Given the vertex of a parabola, finding the self-polar triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections, projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry

Given the point $R=[1:-4:0]$ of the parabola $\mathscr{P}: x^2+y^2-2xy+4x+4y=0$, find a self-polar triangle for $\mathscr{P}$ with vertex in $R$.

Now, a self-polar triangle is composed by a point $P \in r_{\infty} \setminus \mathscr{P}$, then we find the polar line $Pol_{\mathscr{P}}(P) = P^tCX=0$, where $C$ is the matrix which represents the conic section and $X$ the general point $[x_0:x_1:x_2]$. Then we calculate $Pol_{\mathscr{P}}(P) \setminus r_{\infty}$ finding a point $Q$, if $P$ isn't orthogonal to Q, we must change $P$ with a $P'\in r_{\infty} \setminus \mathscr{P}$ s.t. $P'Q=0$ and so $Pol_{\mathscr{P}}(P')$ will be the axis of symmetry of $\mathscr{P}$. Finally $Pol_{\mathscr{P}}(Q) \cap \mathscr{P}$ gives the vertex $R$.

How to do this process having $R$?

Comment: I deleted my answer for the time being since I feel I'm missing something here. When you wrote about *the* self-polar triangle I had the impression this was something rare, but now it seems to me that you can start with any point, pick a second point on its polar and then complete that to a self-polar triangle. So 3 real degees of freedom there. With one vertex on the conic the triangle will degenerate, with two points and two lines coinciding. Is this the situation you have in mind? How unique do you expect the result to be?

Comment: What does $r_\infty\setminus\mathscr P$ mean? A point at infinity not on the conic, or a point at infinity and on the conic, i.e. the point of contact with the line at infinity? Why does infinity play a special role here anyway, isn't the whole setup fully projective? What's the geometric meaning behind $P'Q=0$? Do you want homogeneous coordinate vectors to be orthogonal? Why? Is $\triangle PQR$ your self-polar triangle? Or $\triangle P'QR$ or something else?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain what I mean better: to built the self-polar triangle (in this case, being a parabola, a semi-self-polar one), we can choose a point $P$ at infinity not on the conic. The polar of $P$ respect of the conic is given by $^tPCX=0$ where $C$ is the matrix representing the conic and $X$ the general point. The second point $Q$ is given by the intersection of the polar of $P$ and the infinity: the polar with $x_0=0$. If $P$ and $Q$ weren't orthogonal, you can't change $Q$, but you can do so with $P$, choosing a $P'$ s.t. $P'Q=0$

Comment: This is because the aim is using the vertex of the triangle to built an affinity $\in$ Euclidean Group that brings the conic in the canonical form. So, the third vertex $R$ is also the vertex of the parabola in homogeneous coordinates, and it is given by the intersection of the polar of $Q$ respect to the conic and the conic itself. $R$ will be the only vertex of the triangle not at infinity, then your affinity will be composed, in the order, by $R$, $P$, and $Q$ as column vectors of a matrix. What I have to do in this case, given $R$ respect to the parabola, is find $Q$ and $P$

Comment: If $P$ is at infinity, then its polar will intersect the line at infinity at the contact point with the conic. So $Q$ would represent the point at infinity in the direction of the symmetry axis, which also happens to be $C^{-1}\cdot[1:0:0]$, the pole of the line at infinity. Now you could compute $P'$ as the point at infinity orthogonal to $Q$, or as the pole of the line between $Q$ and $R$. If $R$ is the vertex then both definitions would agree. I'd not call the resulting triangle self-polar, though. Perhaps a definition of “semi-self-polar triangle” might help.

Comment: OK, I guess you *can* call a triangle self-dual if two edges are tangents and the third is the polar line of the opposite vertex. I had always pictured self-dual as every line is the polar of the *opposite* vertex, which doesn't make a lot of sense with tangents and points on the conic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ lies on $\mathscr P$, so its polar line is the tangent to $\mathscr P$ at $R$. Another vertex of the triangle must lie on this line, but no other point on this line lies on its own polar, which means that the third vertex of the triangle must do so. Therefore, the third vertex, too, lies on $\mathscr P$. So, choose any other point $Q$ on $\mathscr P$ as a vertex of the self-polar triangle that you are constructing. The remaining vertex is the pole of the line through $P$ and $Q$, which is the intersection of the tangents to $\mathscr P$ at those points.

From the comments to your question, this is a step in constructing an affinity that converts $\mathscr P$ into standard form. Assuming, then, that this standard form is $y^2=4px$, you can also construct such an affinity from three known lines: the line at infinity, which is fixed by any affinity, the tangent at $R$, which will be mapped to the $y$-axis, and the line through $R$ parallel to $\mathscr P$’s axis, which will be mapped to the $x$-axis. The rows of the matrix of this affinity are just the homogeneous representations of these lines. If you adjust their signs and scale factors appropriately, you can always arrange for the coefficient of $y^2$ in the transformed equation to be $1$ and the coefficient of $x$ to be negative.